# How do I get the site id in the same function that created the site?

Tags: php, wordpress, function, endpoint

I'm writing some php functions to work off of endpoints, specficially one that takes the input of a form to create a site within a wp multi-site. In terms of progress, the code below will take the input and create a site with the correct path and domain, but none of the meta information is being added.

```
  public function create_endpoint($request) {
        $key = $request['key'];

//Capturing user-input from form 
        if ($this->validate_key($key)) {
              $title = $request['name'];
              $slug = $request['slug'];
              $admin_user = $request['admin_user'];
              $site_owner = $request['site_owner'];
              $site_ouc = $request['site_ouc'];
              $registered = $request['registered'];
              $service_tier = $request['service_tier'];
              $service_offering = $request['service_offering'];
              
//Site creation process
                $domain = 'localhost';
                $path = 'wordpress/'.$request['slug'];

                $user_id = get_user_by( 'login', $this->admin_user );

                $network_id = get_network()->id;

                if ( !empty($title) and !empty($domain) and !empty($path) ) {
                  wpmu_create_blog($domain, $path, $title, $user_id);


                  $site_id = get_blog_id_from_url( $domain, $path);

                  //Adding in meta-data
                      update_site_meta( $site_id, 'site_owner' , $site_owner);
                      update_site_meta( $site_id, 'site_ouc' , $site_ouc);
                      update_site_meta( $site_id, 'registered' , $registered);
                      update_site_meta( $site_id, 'service_tier' , $service_tier);
                      update_site_meta( $site_id, 'service_offering' , $service_offering);

                  return $site_id;

                }
                else {
                  return "Not enough information";
                }

        }
         else {
            return $this->invalid_key_message;
        }
    }
```

The root problem being that when I return the `$site_id` I always get `0`, so the `update_site_meta` functions have nothing to work with.

```
if ( !empty($title) and !empty($domain) and !empty($path) ) {
                  wpmu_create_blog($domain, $path, $title, $user_id);

                  return $site_id;
```

Any insight or thoughts are welcome, I have been working against a wall.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looking at he [docs](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wpmu_create_blog/#return) it seems `wpmu_create_blog` should return the blog id... so you could update that part of your code to below:

```
// save id returned from creating the new site
$site_id = wpmu_create_blog($domain, $path, $title, $user_id);

// delete this line
// $site_id = get_blog_id_from_url( $domain, $path);

//Adding in meta-data
```

Answer (score 1):

According to WordPress documentation, the wpmu_create_blog returns the Site ID if the creation was successful:

https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wpmu_create_blog/#return

I haven't tested it, but this change in your snippet of code should work:

```
   public function create_endpoint($request)
    {
        $key = $request['key'];

        //Capturing user-input from form 
        if ($this->validate_key($key)) {
            $title = $request['name'];
            $slug = $request['slug'];
            $admin_user = $request['admin_user'];
            $site_owner = $request['site_owner'];
            $site_ouc = $request['site_ouc'];
            $registered = $request['registered'];
            $service_tier = $request['service_tier'];
            $service_offering = $request['service_offering'];

            //Site creation process
            $domain = 'localhost';
            $path = 'wordpress/' . $request['slug'];

            $user_id = get_user_by('login', $this->admin_user);

            $network_id = get_network()->id;

            if (!empty($title) and !empty($domain) and !empty($path)) {
                $site_id = wpmu_create_blog($domain, $path, $title, $user_id);

                //Adding in meta-data
                update_site_meta($site_id, 'site_owner', $site_owner);
                update_site_meta($site_id, 'site_ouc', $site_ouc);
                update_site_meta($site_id, 'registered', $registered);
                update_site_meta($site_id, 'service_tier', $service_tier);
                update_site_meta($site_id, 'service_offering', $service_offering);

                return $site_id;
            } else {
                return "Not enough information";
            }
        } else {
            return $this->invalid_key_message;
        }
    }
```